# Is there a way to fix the "true" received warning for a "absolute" non-boolean attribute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

```
 return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="flex">
        <Sidebar />
        <div className="content ">
          <Routes>
            <Route  path='/' exact='true' component={<Home />}/>
            <Route  path='StartWorkflow' exact='true' component={<StartWorkflow />}/>
            <Route  path='Myform' exact='true' component={<Myform />}/>
            <Route  path='Mytask' exact='true' component={<Mytask />}/>
            <Route  path='Workflowlist' exact='true' component={<Workflowlist />}/>
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer/> 
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `exact`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: exact="true" or exact={value.toString()}.

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to do `exact={true}`?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass a string. As Nicholas Tower commented: you should pass exact={true} or even simplify it as `<Route path='/' exact component={<Home />}/>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I tried it and still the same warning.

Comment: Oh, are you using react-router 6? The exact prop doesn't exist in version 6, so just delete that. `path="StartWorkflow"` is already exact. If you want it to *not* be exact, you use an asterisk in the route like `path="StartWorkflow/*"`